# How to Correctly implement a model which uses multiple choices?

Tags: django, django-models

I was wondering what is the correct way to implement multiple choices in django-models.

What I want to do:
I want to have a set of choices (each is just a String) and save them somehow. Additionally it should be possible to choose none, one or multiple options.

I am pretty sure that [django.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) is not the right thing to use here.

Is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) really the right thing to use and if so... how shall I implement it?

Regards and thanks in advance,
Senad

Edit:

I've created a simple example. Would that be the right way to implement this?

```
class alert(models.Model):
  alertTime = models.DateTimeField('time when alert is triggered')
  daysOfWeek = models.ManyToManyField(day, blank=True, null=True)

class day(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and then a fixture which fills "day" with all days of the week?

Comment: That's an OK way to implement it, although in the specific case of days then choices is a better way to go (unless you expect people to be adding new days of the week!).

Comment: yeah... but i want to be able to choose none, one or multiple days... in that case choices aren't that good, right?

and my use case is much more complicated than that. just wanted to stay simple ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question.  `Field.choices` is ruled out if you need to select multiple options. `ManyToManyField` works fine and has the advantage that you can change the choices without changing the code, if needed.  You've already linked to the documentation for ManyToManyField, so just go ahead and follow that.  You might also load the default choices using a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: uhhh okay... and how do i implement it correctly?
I mean how to write the Model? (will update question)